# how to change the clock image of the timepicker

Tags: android, timepicker, android-timepicker

I'm setting up a CustomTimePicker, and I need to change the clock Image of the time picker with any other clock image or icon.

```
    <TimePicker
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:timePickerMode="clock"
        />
```

"Is their any styling or something else possible to exchange the icon to the clock with my icon or image"

Comment: See if this answer where he showed how to create a custom style for `TimePicker` on Android with different colors and attributes helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51037169/11040422

Comment: thanks both of you but I have to change the clock icon with my clock icon. Please provide information regarding to this and how to change the clock icon with my own icon

Comment: I have to design fully customize time picker with custom clock and custom dial to select

Comment: I used TimePickerDialog. It will show a dialog just like iphone. If you want that, i can share code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing TimePickerDialog Styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51036919/changing-timepickerdialog-styles)

Comment: Sure @Varun your help would be appriciated

Answer (score 0):

In timepicker, there is  an important attribute:

```
 android:timePickerMode="spinner" or "clock"
```

and to backgroung color set  use theme:

```
android:theme="@style/TimePickerTheme"
```

Comment: sorry but it is not my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 validTillTime.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            KeyboardUtility.hideKeyboard(CreatePassActivityTwo.this);
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                TimePickerUtility.getTime(CreatePassActivityTwo.this).show();
                validFrom = 0;
                return false;
            }
            return true;
```

validTillTime is an EditText here.

```
public class TimePickerUtility {

public static TimePickerDialog getTime(final Context context) {

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timeSetListener =
            new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

                    TimePickerListener timePickerListener = (TimePickerListener) context;
                    timePickerListener.onReceiveTime(hourOfDay, minute);
                }
            };

    return new TimePickerDialog(context,
            R.style.TimePickerTheme, timeSetListener, hour, minute, false);
}

public interface TimePickerListener {

    void onReceiveTime(int hour, int minute);
}
```

implement TimePickerListener in your activity.

```
 @Override
public void onReceiveTime(int hour, int minute) {
    if (validFrom == 1) {
        validFromTime.setText(TimeFormatterUtility.getFormattedTime(hour, minute));
    } else {
        validTillTime.setText(TimeFormatterUtility.getFormattedTime(hour, minute));
    }
}

 <style name="TimePickerTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/buttonColor</item>
    <item name="android:timePickerStyle">@style/TimePickerStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="TimePickerStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.TimePicker">

    <item name="android:headerBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:timePickerMode">spinner</item>
    <item name="android:headerTimeTextAppearance">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
```