# How to change divider color in Timepicker dialog in android

Tags: android, android-studio, timepicker

How to change timepicker divider dialog programmatically in android.As I used below theme the default color its showing blue.I need to change it to red.

```
 TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(context, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_NoActionBar, myTimeListener, hour, minute, false);
    timePickerDialog.setTitle("Schedule Reminders");
    timePickerDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Set", timePickerDialog);
    timePickerDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
    timePickerDialog.show();
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCmsy.jpg)

Comment: You must change the theme in the constructor parameter. Use custom theme you have created instead of android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_NoActionBar. See also:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/51037169

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this item to your main theme

```
 <item name="numberPickerStyle">@style/MyApp.NumberPicker</item>
```

set custom divider color in this style

```
 <style name="MyApp.NumberPicker" parent="Widget.Holo.NumberPicker">
   <item name="selectionDivider">@color/white</item>
 </style>
```

Comment: attribute 'android:attr/selectionDivider' is private. Im getting this